# Embedding Python 3 - no builtins?

Tags: python, python-3.x, embed, python-embedding

After much hair loss, I'm looking for help.

I'm embedding Python 3.3 into a simple app.  One unusual aspect is Python isn't on the path, but it all seems to load OK.  But for some reason, nothing can be executed.

Below is a small example program that shows the error:

**EDIT**: I know the reference counting is horrible -- this is just a simple example.

```
SetDllDirectory(L"D:\\dev\\python\\python33"); //so Python33.dll can be delay-loaded since not in the path

Py_Initialize();
PyObject* pGlobals = PyDict_New();
if (PyDict_GetItemString(pGlobals, "__builtins__") == NULL) 
{
    PyObject* pMod = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins"); <-- always succeeds
    if(NULL != pMod)
        PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, "__builtins__", pMod);
}

PyObject* pResult = PyRun_String("import sys", 0, pGlobals, pGlobals); <-- always fails

if (PyErr_Occurred()) 
{
    //PyErr_Fetch returns:
    //<class 'SyntaxError'>  
    //('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 6, 'import sys'))
}
```

I have tried a variety of ways to import and define builtins, including various attempts shown below:

```
PyObject* pMod = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins");
PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, "builtins", pMod);
PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, "__builtins__", pMod);

PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());
PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, "builtins", PyEval_GetBuiltins());
```

None of them work -- the error is identical with each.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it path related?  Something about builtins that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That error doesn't look like a problem with the builtins - it's a `SyntaxError`, not a `NameError`. But I don't know what could cause it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with the start symbol set to [`Py_file_input`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#Py_file_input) and use [`PyEval_GetBuiltins`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/reflection.html#PyEval_GetBuiltins).

Edit: the correct dict key to set is `"__builtins__"`.

Comment: THANK YOU!  Py_file_input was the secret!